# DbDataReader para de ler depois de um tempo

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Quando o banco de dados está no começo, funciona perfeitamente, após algum tempo de uso, o objeto não retorna nada e a consulta não funciona.

Esse é o fonte:

```
using (DbCommand cmd = CreateCommand(conn, sql.ToString()))
{
    List<TagPojo> tags = new List<TagPojo>();
    AddParameter(cmd, "@tag", DadoTagPojo.Tag);
    AddParameter(cmd, "@dtIni", FData(formataData));
    AddParameter(cmd, "@dtFim", FData(formataData2));


    using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            TagPojo tag = new TagPojo();
            ExtrairDados(dr, tag);
            tags.Add(tag);
        }

        return tags;
    }
}
```

Comment: Neste trecho não consigo ver nenhum motivo para acontecer isto. Pode ser problema em como chama isto ou o que está dentro de `ExtrairDados()`. Também fica complicado entender o que é "o banco de dados está no começo".

Comment: Ele nem chega a entrar no while como se a consulta retornasse null, porém ao jogar a consulta direta no banco, funciona. Quando disse banco de dados no começo, quis dizer um banco novo com poucas informações cadastradas.

Comment: Eu tinha um problema semelhante em um programa que precisava ficar rodando 24h, nas primeiras horas executando ele funcionava bem, mas depois de algumas horas toda consulta retornava null e não gerava erro nenhum durante a pesquisa. Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça achei alguns tópicos falando que o problema era a VM que segurava as conexões mesmo quando você utilizava o Dispose() ou ela dentro de um using(), para que quando você instanciasse uma nova conexão igual, ele simplesmente reaproveitava aquela já criada. E nesse momento é que acontecia o erro.

Comment: Verifique o estado da conexão e a configuração de connection pool.

Comment: E como solucionou isso Christian?